# Does regex automatically ignore trailing whitespace?

Tags: python, regex, nltk

Why do these two expressions return the same output?

```
phillip = '#awesome '

nltk.re_show('\w+|[^\w\s]+', phillip)
```

vs.

```
nltk.re_show('\w+|[^\w]+', phillip)
```

Both return:

```
{#}{awesome}
```

Why doesn't the second one return

```
{#}{awesome}{ }?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this that `nltk` right-strips whitespace in strings before applying the regex.

See [the source code](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/util.html) (or you could `import inspect` and `print inspect.get_source(nltk.re_show)`)

```
def re_show(regexp, string, left="{", right="}"):
    """docstring here -- I stripped it for  brevity"""
    print(re.compile(regexp, re.M).sub(left + r"\g<0>" + right, string.rstrip()))
```

In particular, see the `string.rstrip()`, which strips all trailing whitespace.

For example, if you make sure that your `phillip` string does not have a space to the right:

```
nltk.re_show('\w+|[^\w]+', phillip + '.')
# {#}{awesome}{ .}
```

Not sure why `nltk` would do this, it seems like a bug to me...

Comment: Thanks! I agree, it seems strange.

Answer (score -1):

[`\w`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) looks to match `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. And since you are looking for one OR the other (1+ "word" characters OR 1+ non-"word" characters), it matches the first character as a `\w` character and keeps going until it hits a non-match .

If you do a global match, you will see that there is another match containing the space (the first non-"word" character).

Comment: Judging from the results that were returned, it appears that he's doing a global match (note how it matched both the number sign and the word "awesome").  His second pattern `\w+|[^\w]+` matches either a string of one or more word characters, or a string of one or more negated word characters, so theoretically it should match ` `.  The pattern seems to be working when I try it in regex101, so I'm not sure what OP's problem is.

Comment: He is already doing a global match, as evidenced by `#` and `awesome` being matched separately. The first character is '#' which is definitely a non-word character.

Comment: Good point, yea I wonder what the problem is. [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/lL1lI7) has it working fine (I added a capturing group so its easier to see).